# How to capture tcp request packets?

Tags: python, sockets, packet-sniffers, sniffing, sniffer

I am trying ti capture tcp request(inbound) packets. as it describe in the black hat python book this is the sniffer code. but this sniffer does not capture tcp request packets. i need to capture from windows running environment.

```
class IP(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("version", c_ubyte, 4),
        ("ihl", c_ubyte, 4),
        ("tos", c_ubyte),
        ("len", c_ushort),
        ("id", c_ushort),
        ("offset", c_ushort),
        ("ttl", c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num", c_ubyte),
        ("sum", c_ushort),
        ("src", c_uint32),
        ("dst", c_uint32)
    ]

    def __new__(self, socket_buffer=None):
        return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)

    def __init__(self, socket_buffer=None):

        # map protocol constants to their names
        self.protocol_map = {1:"ICMP", 6:"TCP", 17:"UDP"}

        self.src_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("@I",self.src))
        self.dst_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("@I",self.dst))

        # human readable protocol
        try:
            self.protocol = self.protocol_map[self.protocol_num]
        except:
            self.protocol = str(self.protocol_num)

if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)

sniffer.bind((host, 0))
sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# to set up promiscuous mode
if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

try:
    while True:
        # read in a packet
        raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]

        # create an IP header from the first 20 bytes of the buffer
        ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:])

        # print out the protocol that was detected and the hosts
        print "Protocol: %s %s -> %s " % (ip_header.protocol, ip_header.src_address, ip_header.dst_address)
```

Comment: Are you running with admin privileges?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes i am running with admin privileges. I tried both linux and windows environments

Comment: Are these packets on a wireless or wired network?  If it is wireless you may need to set your wireless adapter into permissive mode

Comment: @BrianCain those packets are wireless

Comment: Can you try the same code on a wired connection.  Also, if you install Wireshark, do you see the packets in question?

Comment: @BrianCain i tried with both wired and wireless. I used wireshark. it capture all incoming and  outgoing packets. but python script only captures outgoing packets.

Answer (score 2):

> I used wireshark. it capture all incoming and outgoing packets. but python script only captures outgoing packets.

Wireshark uses libpcap/WinPcap, which uses the OS's packet capture mechanism (libpcap) or a mechanism provided by a driver that's part of WinPcap (WinPcap) to capture packets.

That's *not* the mechanism that you're using.  Given that your code is in Python, you might want to look at using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: I highly recommend the use of scapy, however it is designed as a Linux tool.  It can be installed on Windows, but I've found it to be more painful than benificial.